# Python telegram api отправить файл post

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Хочу отправить файл POST запрососм с python без дополнительных библиотек

Данный код не срабатывает:

```
def send_document(filename, token, chat_id):
     url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'+token+'/sendDocument'
     data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'caption': 'Результат парсинга'}
     with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
         files = {'document': f}
         response = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
         print(response.json())
```

Функцию вызываю так:

```
filen1ame = "путь/до/файла.7z"
tokent = "token iz botfather"
chatid = chatidfdp #циферный, соответствует чату с ботом в который шлю

send_document(filen1ame, tokent, chatid)
```

При этом у меня еще подключен php вебхук